# Proxy a remote server as localhost

Tags: ssh, linux-networking, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, localhost

There is a server running in a "remotehost:some_port". I can connect to it from my linux machine like `telnet remotehost remoteport`. I have an application in the linux machine that is configured to connect to `127.0.0.1:7576` where it expects the server to run. I can change the configuration to connect to remote server instead but is there a way to proxy the remote server so that I don't have to change the configuration? I can do ssh port binding (like `ssh -L...`) but the remote server does not ssh. Is there an easy way other than creating a process that listens on localhost and forwards the packets to the remote server?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to run a proxy locally, such as nginx.
The [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html) is pretty good with relevant examples.

Here is a minimal, yet more complete, example:

```
worker_processes auto;
error_log error.log;
events { }
stream {
  server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:7576;
    proxy_pass REMOTE_HOST:7576;
  }
}
```

Below is an example of running nginx in the foreground with the above configuration in a file named: `nginx.conf`.

```
nginx -p $PWD -c nginx.conf -g "daemon off; pid nginx.pid; error_log /dev/stderr;"
```

The -g option supplies global configurations. `daemon off` is the one that makes it run in the foreground. `pid nginx.pid` puts the pid file in the working directory since default puts it in logs directory that probably isn't there. `error_log /dev/stderr` send error logs to the console, I've found this is needed to be in the `-g` option when running with `daemon off`, otherwise it may try to log to the default location before reading the error_log configuration from the file.

Comment: Does it work even if the server is not a http server?

Comment: 2018/09/28 19:16:03 [emerg] 2277#2277: unknown directive "stream" in /home/bala/nginx.conf:4

Comment: nginx version: https://pastebin.com/raw/P8wZSjZ7

Comment: added load_module. Getting this error:
nginx: [emerg] the invalid "proxy_pass" parameter in /home/bala/nginx.conf:8

Comment: I don't know what the `--with-stream=dynamic` does, but I just built nginx-1.14.0 with `./configure --with-stream && make` and ran it directly from the `objs` directory like so: `./nginx -p "$PWD" -c nginx.conf -g "daemon off; pid nginx.pid; error_log /dev/stderr;"` and it worked as expected.